# Writing a "find and replace for certain empty cells" function in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe that looks roughly like this:

```
March_created_at    March_email March_type  April_created_at April_email    April_type
3/11/12 7:28    jeremy@asynk.ch PushEvent   4/1/12 4:03                     PushEvent
3/11/12 7:28    jeremy@asynk.ch PushEvent   4/1/12 4:03                     PushEvent
3/11/12 7:28    jeremy@asynk.ch PushEvent   4/1/12 4:03                     PushEvent
3/11/12 7:28    jeremy@asynk.ch PushEvent   4/1/12 7:03     high            IssuesEvent
3/11/12 11:06   medium          PushEvent   4/1/12 13:57    medium          PushEvent
3/11/12 11:06   medium          PushEvent   4/1/12 13:57    medium          PushEvent
3/11/12 11:06   medium          PushEvent   4/1/12 13:57    medium          PushEvent
3/11/12 12:46                   PushEvent   
3/11/12 12:46                   PushEvent   
3/11/12 12:46                   PushEvent
```

The full dataset can be found [here](https://github.com/aronlindberg/VOSS-Sequencing-Toolkit/blob/master/rubinius_rubinius_sequencing/output.csv) as a CSV file

Now, I'm using a function (thanks to Hadley Wickham) to replace certain email addresses with strings (such as "high" and "medium").

```
# the find-and-replace function
replace_all <- function(df, pattern, replacement) {
  char <- vapply(df, function(x) is.factor(x) || is.character(x), logical(1))
  df[char] <- lapply(df[char], str_replace_all, pattern, replacement)  
  df
}

# the function call
df.new <- replace_all(df, fixed("bford@engineyard.com"), "core")
```

However, there are some cells where there is nothing (e.g. rows 8-10 in column "March_email") written. I want to find all of these cells and replace them with the string "low" *if* the following condition holds:

*There is a date attached to the same month (e.g. rows 8-10 has dates in the "March_created_at column, so the empty cells in "March_email" indicate missing data that needs to be replaced)

This means that if there is no date attached to that row where there is a blank cell in the email column (e.g. columns 8-10 for April), nothing should be replaced there. It is simply no data for that range.

How can I accomplish this in R?

**Appendix:** Here is a dput() of the head of the dataset:

```
structure(list(March_created_at = c("2012-03-11 07:28:04", "2012-03-11 07:28:04", 
"2012-03-11 07:28:04", "2012-03-11 07:28:19", "2012-03-11 07:28:19", 
"2012-03-11 07:28:19"), March_actor_attributes_email = c("jeremy@asynk.ch", 
"jeremy@asynk.ch", "jeremy@asynk.ch", "jeremy@asynk.ch", "jeremy@asynk.ch", 
"jeremy@asynk.ch"), March_type = c("PushEvent", "PushEvent", 
"PushEvent", "PushEvent", "PushEvent", "PushEvent"), April_created_at = c("2012-04-01     04:03:13", 
"2012-04-01 04:03:13", "2012-04-01 04:03:13", "2012-04-01 07:03:11", 
"2012-04-01 07:03:11", "2012-04-01 07:03:11"), April_actor_attributes_email = c("", 
"", "", "high", "high", "high"), April_type = c("PushEvent", 
"PushEvent", "PushEvent", "IssuesEvent", "IssuesEvent", "IssuesEvent"
), May_created_at = c("2012-05-01 00:16:05", "2012-05-01 00:16:05", 
"2012-05-01 00:16:05", "2012-05-01 01:03:19", "2012-05-01 01:03:19", 
"2012-05-01 01:03:19"), May_actor_attributes_email = c("john.firebaugh@gmail.com", 
"john.firebaugh@gmail.com", "john.firebaugh@gmail.com", "mitch.tishmack@gmail.com", 
"mitch.tishmack@gmail.com", "mitch.tishmack@gmail.com"), May_type = c("PushEvent", 
"PushEvent", "PushEvent", "IssueCommentEvent", "IssueCommentEvent", 
"IssueCommentEvent"), June_created_at = c("2012-06-01 00:25:05", 
"2012-06-01 00:25:05", "2012-06-01 00:25:05", "2012-06-01 00:42:29", 
"2012-06-01 00:42:29", "2012-06-01 00:42:29"), June_actor_attributes_email =     c("michaelklishin@me.com", 
"michaelklishin@me.com", "michaelklishin@me.com", "", "", ""), 
    June_type = c("IssueCommentEvent", "IssueCommentEvent", "IssueCommentEvent", 
    "PushEvent", "PushEvent", "PushEvent"), July_created_at = c("2012-07-01 13:46:20", 
    "2012-07-01 13:46:20", "2012-07-02 11:53:37", "2012-07-02 11:53:37", 
    "2012-07-02 12:27:30", "2012-07-02 12:27:30"), July_actor_attributes_email = c("medium", 
    "medium", "ryoqun@gmail.com", "ryoqun@gmail.com", "ryoqun@gmail.com", 
    "ryoqun@gmail.com"), July_type = c("PushEvent", "PushEvent", 
    "CreateEvent", "CreateEvent", "PushEvent", "PushEvent"), 
    August_created_at = c("2012-08-01 00:04:09", "2012-08-01 00:04:09", 
    "2012-08-01 00:04:42", "2012-08-01 00:04:42", "2012-08-01 00:05:04", 
    "2012-08-01 00:05:04"), August_actor_attributes_email = c("jeremy@asynk.ch", 
    "jeremy@asynk.ch", "jeremy@asynk.ch", "jeremy@asynk.ch", 
    "jeremy@asynk.ch", "jeremy@asynk.ch"), August_type = c("IssueCommentEvent", 
    "IssueCommentEvent", "IssuesEvent", "IssuesEvent", "IssueCommentEvent", 
    "IssueCommentEvent"), September_created_at = c("2012-09-01 18:12:24", 
    "2012-09-01 18:12:24", "2012-09-01 23:51:18", "2012-09-01 23:51:18", 
    "2012-09-02 00:34:54", "2012-09-02 00:34:54"), September_actor_attributes_email = c("ryoqun@gmail.com", 
    "ryoqun@gmail.com", "ryoqun@gmail.com", "ryoqun@gmail.com", 
    "ryoqun@gmail.com", "ryoqun@gmail.com"), September_type = c("CommitCommentEvent", 
    "CommitCommentEvent", "CreateEvent", "CreateEvent", "PushEvent", 
    "PushEvent"), October_created_at = c("2012-10-01 07:48:38", 
    "2012-10-01 10:01:40", "2012-10-01 10:01:43", "2012-10-01 10:17:00", 
    "2012-10-01 16:08:29", "2012-10-01 18:06:46"), October_actor_attributes_email = c("medium", 
    "medium", "medium", "medium", "", "core"), October_type = c("PushEvent", 
    "IssuesEvent", "PushEvent", "PushEvent", "ForkEvent", "PullRequestEvent"
    )), .Names = c("March_created_at", "March_actor_attributes_email", 
"March_type", "April_created_at", "April_actor_attributes_email", 
"April_type", "May_created_at", "May_actor_attributes_email", 
"May_type", "June_created_at", "June_actor_attributes_email", 
"June_type", "July_created_at", "July_actor_attributes_email", 
"July_type", "August_created_at", "August_actor_attributes_email", 
"August_type", "September_created_at", "September_actor_attributes_email", 
"September_type", "October_created_at", "October_actor_attributes_email", 
"October_type"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Unfortunately your explanation does not match your dataset. for e.g. rows `8-10` `March_email` is actually `March_actor_attributes_email` and also not blank.

Comment: Yes, I made a number of edits in the example to make it fit graphically. The example on top is just an example that I use to illustrate what I need to get done. What is important is the principle , not exactly how it looks.

Comment: Have you looked at the ifelse() function?

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to use the ifelse() function?

Comment: ifelse(x==0, print("zero"), print("non-zero"))

Answer (score 0):

I think either one should work in principle.

```
1)
df2[df2$March_actor_attributes_email == "" & df2$March_created_at !="","March_actor_attributes_email"] <- "low"

2)
df2$March_actor_attributes_email <- ifelse(df2$March_actor_attributes_email == "" & df2$March_created_at !="", "low", df2$March_actor_attributes_email)
```

The tricky part would be with the date column.  You may want to make sure that the field actually contains a date as a opposed to just being non-blank, but that depends on how you have things structured.